# How to disable HTML5 audio from download mp3/ogg on load?

Tags: html, audio

I am looking for a way to stop audio element from downloading mp3/ogg, im using .mp3 files on my website and it slow down my site alot.

In following Code example, autoplay="false" preload="none" set but still audio is downloading.

```html
 <audio controls autoplay="false" preload="none">
      <source src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lrdjzp8jEq1r2hak2o1.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
```

Comment: Don't put it on your page if you don't want to use it...  what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I didn't quite know how to phrase the question, take a look at this screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/aU7wlDV.png, my page size is 16.8mb tested on pingdom.com

Comment: Well, yeah, your page has a big MP3 file on it.  Who cares what Pingdom says... what matters is the user experience.  You're doing what you're supposed to do.  That page isn't going to load that MP3 until everything else is pretty much done downloading.  Even then, it might not load the whole thing... it might only load part of it.  Doubtful Pingdom is taking that into account.  Your page is probably fine as-is.